# Getting "System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." error while calling web api

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

In my application, there is a functionality to extract reports based on a date range. In the background, it is calling my Web API with authentication(A), which consists of api caller functionality using httpclient, which is calling another non-secured DMZ server API (B) and a DMZ API-caliing WCF service (C) to collect data from the database.
My problem is that whenever I select a large date range, I get the following error in my WebAPI (A).

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at LRAS.OrderServices.Core.Helpers.ApiCaller.d__4.MoveNext()

What I have tried: I have increased the httpclient timeout from 300 to 1000 seconds, but it is breaking nearly every minute.

Answer (score 1):

You can try several methods:
1.Configure the service point security protocol and select the `SecurityProtocolType` that suits you (Tls12, Ssl3, Tls, Tls11).

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

[C# System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886223/c-sharp-system-net-webexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpe) 
2.Set the ConnectionClose property of HttpClient.

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
```

[HttpClient throwing "An error occurred while sending the request."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661696/httpclient-throwing-an-error-occurred-while-sending-the-request)

3.Try to hold the request long enough for it to complete normally and receive a valid response.

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "3600");
```

[.NET HttpClient - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297345/net-httpclient-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

Comment: Thanks Lan Huang for your feedback. I tried all these solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: You can check the link I provided to find the solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459475/system-net-webexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-wa/12764845